# Why can not I drag a component to the inspector in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I do my exercise following a blog,and met with trouble.

After coding, I create a ShapeFactory asset in project,and sign the prefabs.size to 3,add the Shape component to a cube,after these work, I tried to drag the cube to the ShapeFactory asset,but it stoped by editor without nothing info but  a forbident icon.

Here  the code  is:

ShapeFactory.cs

```c#
public class ShapeFactory :ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private Shape[] prefabs;
}
```

Shape.cs

```c#
public class Shape : PersistableObject
{
    private int shapeId=int.MinValue;
}
```

PersistableObject.cs

```c#
public class PersistableObject : MonoBehaviour {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ScriptableObject` are assets that "live" only in the **Assets** and are not related to any Scene.

You (usually) can not have any references from a Scene in a Prefab/asset that lives only in the Assets. The reason is savety. If the according Scene is not loaded then the references simply would not exist.

You would need some kind of persistent dependency injection in order to reconstruct those references once the Scene is loaded (afaik e.g. the serialization system of [Odin Inspector](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/odin-inspector-and-serializer-89041) is capable of that) or use dynamic dependency injection on runtime (some Assets exist for doing that in the [AssetStore](https://assetstore.unity.com/?q=dependency%20injection&orderBy=0) as well).

---

According to the field name `ShapeFactory.prefabs` what you want to use is a [**Prefab**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) of that cube GameObject instead.

Simply drag & drop that cube from the Scene (Hierachy) into the Assets folder (ProjectView). This creates a [Prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) from it. That new created prefab you can now reference in the `ScriptableObject` asset and other prefabs.

---

Before I said `(usually)` because some workarounds exists in case you really need a reference from a Scene. The simpliest one I know would be to use another `ScriptableObject` like e.g.

1. Change your script to

   ```c#
   public class ShapeFactory : ScriptableObject
   {
       [SerializeField] private PersistableObjectReference[] prefabsReferences;
   }
   ```
2. then have the reference type

   ```c#
   [CreateAssetMenu]
   public class PersistableObjectReference : ScriptableObject
   {
       public PersistableObject value;
   }
   ```
3. Then on the according object in the scene have a

   ```c#
   [RequireComponent(typeof(PersistableObject))]
   public class PersistentObjectReferenceSetter : MonoBehaviour
   {
       [SerializeField] private PersistableObjectReference reference;

       // use Awake so it is also called if this object is
       // deactivated in the hierachy
       private void Awake()
       {
           reference.value = GetComponent<PersitableObject>();
       }
   }
   ```

   and now reference the according `PersistableObjectReference` asset in `reference`. This will on runtime set the correct reference from the Scene into the `ScriptableObject` (it will be displayed as `Type missmatch` but work as expected).

Now all you have to do is later instead of using the former `prefabs[index]` rather use `prefabReferences[index].value` in `ShapeFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

**INVALID**: You can't assign scene Game Objects to Scriptable Objects.
Scene Game Objects are in the [Hierarchy Window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Hierarchy.html).

**VALID**: You can assign [Prefabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) to Scriptable Objects.
Prefabs are in the [Project Window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProjectView.html).

Since you're creating a Factory you want the Prefab there and not a scene Game Object.

---

### HOW TO DO SO

To achieve that you can simply do this:

1. **CREATE A PREFAB**: Drag the *-Cube Scene GameObject-* (the one in the Hierarchy Window) to the Project Folder => so you create a prefab
2. **ASSIGN THE PREFAB IN THE SO**: Drag the *-Cube Prefab-* (the one in the Project Window) on the SO.

Now you can use the Prefab in the SO factory for instantiation or any other goal.